# How to do localization in license plate with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, localization, image-recognition

I want to develop an matlab program that can recognise the vehicle plate.

But before it, i have to do localization of the plate in the "CAR" image.

HOW TO DO IT?

I have read many paper that said methods like modified Hough Transform, Bottom hat, vertical smearing, Gabor Filtering..

I Have 2 example codes, but the result image is wrong.

Here is the **my First code** but the result is **wrong**.

```
I = imread('DSC_0512.JPG'); 
BW = im2bw(I,0.4); 
se = strel('rectangle', [2 20]); 
BW_opened = imclose(BW,se); 
figure, imshow(BW_opened,[]) 
s=regionprops(BW_opened,'Area','BoundingBox'); 
[hh,ii] = sort([s.Area],'descend'); 
out = imcrop(I,s(ii(2)).BoundingBox); 
figure,imshow(out);
```

And here is my Second Code and the result is **wrong too**...

```
I = imread('DSC_0512.JPG');
r = I(:,:,1);  %red plane 
g = I(:,:,2);  %green plane
b = I(:,:,3);  %blue plane
BW = (r >= 230) & (r <= 260) & (g >= 160) & (g <= 240) & (b >= 160) & (b <= 240);
s = regionprops(BW, 'Area', 'BoundingBox');
[HH, ii] = sort([s.Area], 'descend');
out = imcrop(I, s(ii(1)).BoundingBox);
imshow(out);
```

Here is examples of my [images](http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r649/farhat1s/DSC_0512_zps17ebed93.jpg) and [this](http://www.nobleforums.com/images/onyxm400/bmw/plate.jpg)

Please help me.. Any suggestionn ??

Answer (score 3):

The Viola-Jones algorithm based on Haar-features is widely used for object detection. It is especially popular for face detection.

You can find an overview about the algorithm on wikipedia and get the original 2001 Viola and Jones paper here: (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.6807)

It is implemented in Matlab's computer vision system toolbox, more specifically the `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` System object does the job.

Sample code can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29437-viola-jones-object-detection

So far, so good. But here is the catch: afaik, Matlab only provides classifiers for faces, eyes, upper body, and so on, but not for license plates. Thus, you need to train the algorithm yourself. Therefore, you will need annotated training samples. These are image for which the license plate location is known. The `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function does that training.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Sebastian's approach. I do believe that the Viola-Jones algorithms doesn't perform well with affine and projective distortions to the image. This is true for faces and should be the same for any other objects.

If the system you are trying to implement can ensure that the number plate is always facing straight at the camera most of the time. This would work well.

Another approach that might be worth exploring is basic text detection. There are multiple algorithms for the same. Since we can safely assume that number plates always contain text on them. You can use the MSER feature algorithm to find this text . You can find the MATLAB implementation [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) . Once Text is detected. Using spacial locality it should be easy enough to extract the location of the number plate within the image. The only case where this would probably fail is when there are damaged number plates.